# Are chrome notifications received via service workers batched or real time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, notifications, service-worker

I am trying to implement Browser Push Notification for my website. I am noticing even though the browser received notification, it doesn't display the notification sometimes.

```
var showNotification = function (event, data) {
    var notificationData = data['data'];
    var title = notificationData['title'];
    var body = notificationData['body'];
    var icon = notificationData['icon'];
    var notificationActionsData = notificationData["actions"];
    var actions = [];

    if(notificationActionsData) {
        for(var i=0; i < notificationActionsData.length; i++) {
            var action = {
                action: "action" + i,
                title: notificationActionsData[i].title,
            };
            actions.push(action);
        }
    }

    var campaignId = notificationData["id"];
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {
        body: body,
        icon: icon,
        data: notificationData,
        tag: notificationData.id,
        actions: actions
    });

    pushowlReporting.tickle(campaignId, "delivery");
};

function processNotification(event) {
    if (event.data) {
        var data = event.data.json();
        showNotification(event, data);
    }
    else {
        fetch("https://" + hostname + "/api/v1/subdomain/" + subdomain + "/campaign/", {'mode': 'no-cors'}).then(
            function (response) {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ', response.status);
                    return;
                }

                // Examine the text in the response
                response.text().then(function (responseText) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(responseText);
                    showNotification(event, data);
                });
            }
        ).catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Fetch Error :', err);
            }
        );
    }
}

self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(processNotification(event));
});
```

My reporting API shows that the notification has been delivered however the browser displays the notification intermittently.

The notification display is quite erratic. Sometimes the notifications will display immediately, while sometimes it doesn't display for a while and all of a sudden all past notifications come in a batch. And at times some notifications don't get displayed at all.

Let me know if am doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function passed to event.waituntil should return a promise. If not the scope would be messed up as the lifetime of the event wouldnt have got extended.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent/waitUntil

```
var showNotification = function (event, data) {
    var notificationData = data['data'];
    var title = notificationData['title'];
    var body = notificationData['body'];
    var icon = notificationData['icon'];
    var notificationActionsData = notificationData["actions"];
    var actions = [];

    if(notificationActionsData) {
        for(var i=0; i < notificationActionsData.length; i++) {
            var action = {
                action: "action" + i,
                title: notificationActionsData[i].title,
            };
            actions.push(action);
        }
    }

    var campaignId = notificationData["id"];
    return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
        body: body,
        icon: icon,
        data: notificationData,
        tag: notificationData.id,
        actions: actions
    }).then(function (succ) {
        pushowlReporting.tickle(campaignId, "delivery");
    });
};
function processNotification(event) {
    if (event.data) {
        var data = event.data.json();
        return showNotification(event, data);
    }
    else {
        return fetch("https://" + hostname + "/api/v1/subdomain/" + subdomain + "/campaign/", {'mode': 'no-cors'}).then(
            function (response) {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ', response.status);
                    return;
                }

                // Examine the text in the response
                response.text().then(function (responseText) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(responseText);
                    showNotification(event, data);
                });
            }
        ).catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Fetch Error :', err);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I have just added return statements to your code. Try this out.